# How do I pass a variable to a kubectl deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

I am trying to make quick tweaks to the compute requests for a large number of deployments rather than having to get a PR approved if it turns out we need to change the numbers slightly. I need to be able to pass just one variable to the yaml file that gets applied.

Example below.

Shell Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

APPCENTER=(pa nyc co nc md sc mi)
for ac in "${APPCENTER[@]}"
do
  kubectl apply -f jobs-reqtweaks.yaml --env=APPCENTER=$ac
  kubectl apply -f queue-reqtweaks.yaml --env=APPCENTER=$ac
  kubectl apply -f web-reqtweaks.yaml --env=APPCENTER=$ac
done
```

YAML deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: example-app
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    appcenter: $APPCENTER
    chart: example-app-0.1.0
    component: deployment-name
    heritage: Tiller
    release: example-app-fb-feature-tp-1121-fb-pod-resizing
  name: $APPCENTER-deployment-name
  namespace: example-app-fb-feature-tp-1121-fb-pod-resizing
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example-app
      appcenter: $APPCENTER
      chart: example-app-0.1.0
      component: deployment-name
      heritage: Tiller
      release: example-app-fb-feature-tp-1121-fb-pod-resizing
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example-app
        appcenter: $APPCENTER
        chart: example-app-0.1.0
        component: deployment-name
        heritage: Tiller
        release: example-app-fb-feature-tp-1121-fb-pod-resizing
    spec:
      containers:
        name: deployment-name
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "400Mi"
            cpu: "10m"
          requests:
            cpu: 11m
            memory: 641Mi
```

Comment: Another solution should be to use helm, https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/

Comment: Already using helm in the repository, too many complications with using that for this simple purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kubectl apply` doesn't accept an `--env` flag (`kubectl apply --help`).

You have various choices:

1. `sed` -- treats the YAML as a text file
2. [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) -- treats YAML as YAML

Define constants:

```sh
# The set of YAML files you want to change
FILES=(
  "jobs-reqtweaks.yaml"
  "queue-reqtweaks.yaml"
  "web-reqtweaks.yaml"
)

# The set of data-centers
APPCENTER=(pa nyc co nc md sc mi)
```

Then, either use `sed`:

```sh
# Iterate over the data-centers
for ac in "${APPCENTER[@]}"
do
  # Iterate over the files
  for FILE in ${FILES[@]}
  do
    sed \
    --expression="s|\$APPCENTER|${ac}|g" \
    ${FILE}| kubectl apply --filename=-
  done
done
```

Or use [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq):

```sh
# Iterate over the data-centers
for ac in "${APPCENTER[@]}"
do
  # Iterate over the files
  for FILE in ${FILES[@]}
  do
    UPDATE="with(select(documentIndex==0)
    ; .metadata.labels.appcenter=\"${ac}\"
    | .metadata.name=\"${ac}-deployment-name\"
    | .spec.selector.matchLabels.appcenter=\"${ac}\"
    | .spec.template.metadata.labels.appcenter=\"${ac}\"
    )"
    yq eval "${UPDATE}" \
    ${FILE}| kubectl apply --filename=-
  done
done
```

Comment: And what should I do to my yaml file to be compatible with this? This answer is somewhat confusing. What is the FILE part about? a b c? I'm lost.

Comment: You showed 3 files in your example e.g. `jobs-reqtweaks.yaml `. I just used placeholders for the filenames (e.g. `a`). Replace `"a" "b" "c"` with your filenames.

Comment: Ok I thought so, but going with yq I still get errors thrown from the yaml file, not sure how that is supposed to look: metadata.name: Invalid value: "$APPCENTER-web": a lowercase RFC 1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character
* spec.template.spec.containers[0].image: Required value...

Comment: Hmmmm.... let me try it again!

Comment: Apologies, I missed one of the changes `metadata.name`. Try the update example above

Comment: In your YAML example, the value is `$APPCENTER-deployment-name` but, in your error, it dislikes `$APPCENTER-web`. It appears that value changes too.... So it may still not work. I'd need to know exactly what is needed for each file. You may need to try your hand with `yq` and form these for yourself.

Comment: The Deployment "mi-queue-check" is invalid: spec.selector: Invalid value: v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"app":"prism", "appcenter":"mi", "chart":"prism-0.1.0", "component":"queue-check", "heritage":"Tiller", "release":"prism-fb-feature-tp-1121-fb-pod-resizing", "tier":"worker"}, MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is immutable

Comment: I can't tell from that error exactly what it has a problem with, something is nil but it lists everything in that whole block.

Comment: The issue appears to be that, once e.g. a `Deployment` is created, it's not permitted to update its `selector.matchLabels`. These are the parameters by which Pods are associated with a Deployment. The only solution (and I'm **not** advising you do this as it will likely break something else) is to delete the Deployment and recreate it.

Comment: See: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50808

Comment: So what I ended up doing is deleting sections of that queue-check yaml file that weren't needed for the changes I was making till it stopped giving me errors. However I think you're right, it's related to that issue you linked.

Answer (score 1):

Your script can use [envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) and be effective:

```
for i in pa nyc co nc md sc mi
do
  export APPCENTER=$i
  envsubst < your_sample_in_the_question.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
done
```

Side note:

```
...
spec:
 containers:
 - name: deployment-name
   resources:
     limits:
       memory: "400Mi"
       cpu: "10m"  # <-- This limit should be greater than requested.
     requests:
       cpu: 11m  # <-- ??
       memory: 641Mi
```

Comment: I thought that only worked for environment variables.

Comment: error: error validating "STDIN": error validating data: [unknown object type "nil" in Deployment.metadata.labels.appcenter

Comment: Missed the line that set the environment variable... further simplified with the updated answer, check it out.

Comment: Weirdly it still gets that error, I dunno. It just doesn't see that as a valid variable I don't think. It thinks it is empty.

Comment: Maybe it's how I have it called in the yaml file? It's as I put it in the original post.

Comment: Tested, the outputs have $APPCENTER replaced correctly. Checkout the updated answer.